# how to check a list of rows against same table

Tags: sql

i have a table like this:

[image]

my query is to list the employees who left the job between 20150131 to 20150228

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: i tried but i am sure that my code is totally wrong ,that,s why i posted question here. @KScandrett

Comment: Part of asking a good question on SO is to show code that is wrong or not working. Then people can see that you've tried and also it gives them something to start from and they can often fix it. That is why people have down-voted your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE Month_ending BETWEEN 20150131 AND 20150228;
```

Next time, first look here :

Comment: it doesn't reach my criteria , i want 1005 as output because he is the only one who left the job in 20150228 @Said Mezhoud

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Emp_id FROM yourTable T1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM yourTable T2
                   WHERE T2.Emp_id = T1.Emp_id
                     AND T2.Month_ending <> T1.Month_ending)
```

Answer largely based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472316/1544886

Answer (score 0):

Use the query

```
SELECT Emp_id 
FROM Employee_details 
WHERE [Month_ending] = '20150131'
AND [Emp_id] NOT IN(
  SELECT [Emp_id]
  FROM Employee_details
  WHERE [Month_ending] = '20150228'
)
```